# How to wrap this in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a piece of code that I am trying to wrap in a function that returns the value of a cookie.

```
document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(s) {
  return s.search('constituency=') == 1
})[0].split(/(=)/).slice(2).join('');
```

In my browser console, this returns the cookie value perfectly. I want to be able to use this value in another function but when I try wrap it in a function it says 'undefined'.

Can anybody help me understand why?

```
function splitValues() {
  document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(s) {
    return s.search('constituency=') == 1
  })[0].split(/(=)/).slice(2).join('');
}
```

Comment: You need to add `return` on line 2, just before `document.cookie`. Right know you function returns `void`, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to return the value

```
function splitValues() { 
   return document.cookie.split( ';' ).filter( 
    function( s ) { 
      return s.search( 'constituency=' ) == 1 
    })[ 0 ].split( /(=)/ ).slice( 2 ).join( '' );
}
```

Notice the `return` before `document`

Comment: Thanks, so simple but it had be stumped for ages!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `return` statement:

```
function splitValues() {
  return document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(s) {
  //^^\\
    return s.search('constituency=') == 1
  })[0].split(/(=)/).slice(2).join('');
}
```

The `return` statement is the first statement inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

In order for a function to work you need to **return the result**. In your case, you only return the result of the `.search()` method inside the function of the `.filter()` method.

You have to **return the result of the `.filter()` method** as a whole as well for it to work: ↓

```
return document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(s) {...}...
```

**The entire function**:

```
function splitValues() {
    return document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(s) {
        return s.search('constituency=') == 1
    })[0].split(/(=)/).slice(2).join('');
}
```